# Como executar um script javascript logo após o envio do formulário? (sem ser o onClick)

Tags: javascript, html5

Quero executar uma função javascript que mostra uma mensagem de carregando na página, ou seja, enquanto a página carrega, a mensagem aparece na tela, com o porém não sei como usar no html5 com o javascript, pois estou usando o `required`(validação dentro do html, sem js)

Ouvi falar da função `onbeforeunload`, mas ela está descontinuada, tem alguma função que substitua ela?

Comment: `onbeforeunload` não esta depreciada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Como executar um script javascript logo após o envio do formulário?"

Evento `onsubmit`.

```
<html>
<script>
function reg() {
  window.captureEvents(Event.SUBMIT);
  window.onsubmit = hit;
}

function hit() {
  console.log('hit');
}
</script>

<body onload="reg();">
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="d"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Documentação e exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit)

Comment: opa, obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria, coloquei exatamente assim '<form name="form1" method="post" action="processamento.php" onSubmit="return gifCarregando();">' junto com o JS assim 'function gifCarregando(){
  $('#aguarde, #blanket').css('display','block'); 
  return true;   
 };' e funcionou, obrigado, :D